# Azure API App Questions - Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I have a few questions regarding the new Azure API apps that I haven't been able to find any detail on:

- Is it possible to protect the swagger endpoint?
- Is it possible to protect the Azure API app with an API key? Or do i have to do it manually via filters?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swagger endpoint is just a regular endpoint of your API app so the access level and authentication provider apply to this endpoint as well.

For protecting API app with API key, right now there is no platform support. Could you please propose this idea at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/287595-api-apps?

Thanks.

Comment: Idea submitted: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/287595-api-apps/suggestions/8131095-add-ability-to-use-api-key-authentication

Comment: This feature request is exactly what we are looking for. Could you please explain which workaround are viable for now? How would you implement an ASP.NET filter which is secure? 

Just checking for a specific key in the header seems not legit to me since an attacker who looks at the network traffic can easily copy the api key.